# Port Mass SD image writer ARCH -> Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, python, sd-card, archlinux

Data: Raspberry Pi 3 B running Raspbian+PIXEL

Hello,
I'm attempting to follow along with [this projec](https://github.com/algoaccess/rpi-mass-image-writer)t where a Raspberry Pi can be used to flash multiple SD cards with an image file as a batch.

The author mentions that the project can be carried out on Raspbian instead of ARCH Linux with a few modifications. That's what I'm attempting to do, but I've run into a bit of a hangup

The steps I've followed are to:
apt-get the i2c-tools, pv and samba, and perform the git clone. All from within /home/pi

From within the project directory i attempt to execute `python writer.py`but get the following output:

[image: attempt to run writer.py]

**I'm having trouble interpreting the output message - clearly there is an incorrect path or a file missing but I'm unsure about how to proceed.**

I've verified the i2c chip is detected by executing `i2cdetect -y 1` and I can see the device at address 0x20.

**EDIT:** hadn't embedded to url. fixed

Comment: "I'm having trouble interpreting the output message" - so am I. Post text!

Comment: It seems writer.py wants to display its state to a char LCD display. Do you have one connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this project on a Raspberry Pi 3 B requires modification of the I2C setup.

In Adafruit_I2C.py line 35 should be uncommented, and line 34 should be commented. This hard-codes the I2C bus as I2C1